# can a HDMI to USB Converter be used to display Games on a laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, usb, hdmi, xbox360

I've been playing around with some gaming tech recently, and I got to thinking: Can a HDMI to USB Converter be used to display Games on a Laptop Screen? I do have access to TV's, but I want to try this nonetheless.

An example of the part I am talking about can be found [here](http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mZvgeKOfDZfVhdA1RNAqv6g.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in current form. The converter is USB to HDMI, not "HDMI-to-USB". It does not work in reverse. These are two entirely different functions, and the HDMI-to-USB does not exist.

The dongle in your link is a **USB device** of video class. The host detects this device and works with it as it is a videocard. This "videocard" outputs HDMI format video stream for your PC monitor. It is OUTPUT.

To accomplish what you want, you would need to design a sort of emulation of PC monitor:
(a) make a HDMI **receiver**;
(b) make a USB device that looks like a video camera, USB webcam class, which uses the HDMI stream and converts it into webcam format;

This it technically doable, but the video lag will be horrible, so gamers will not like it.